# Find empty cells in range, then return contents of another cell in the same row as empty cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel vba code adapted from here (https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/use-isempty-vba-to-check-if-cell-is-blank/) that determines if any cell in a given range is blank. If there are any it returns a msgbx, if there are none, it returns a different msg.

I would like to know if it is possible to return (in the msgbx) the contents of the cell in column E of that same row. That would indicate which is the row with the empty cell that needs to be addressed.

It looks at two columns. Ideally, if both cells are empty in the same row it would only return the contents of the cell in column E once.

Here is the code, can you guys help me modify to do what I am asking?

```
Sub IsEmptyRange()
Dim cell As Range
Dim bIsEmpty As Boolean

bIsEmpty = False
For Each cell In Range("G26:H38,G25,G23:H24,G22,G6:H21,G5,G3:H4")
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
    'An empty cell was found. Exit loop
    bIsEmpty = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell

If bIsEmpty = True Then
    MsgBox "One or more cells are empty"
Else   
    MsgBox "All cells are filled in"
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks!

AR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit. Included comment requests.

```
Option Explicit

Sub IsEmptyRange()
Dim cell As Range
Dim bIsEmpty As Boolean
Dim emptyCellRow As Long
Dim arrRows() As Long, i As Long
Dim arrValues() As String
Dim emptyRow As Variant, emptyRows As String, emptyValues As String
bIsEmpty = False
i = 0
For Each cell In Range("G26:H38,G25,G23:H24,G22,G6:H21,G5,G3:H4")
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
        'An empty cell was found. Exit loop
        emptyCellRow = cell.Row
        bIsEmpty = True

        ReDim Preserve arrRows(i)
        ReDim Preserve arrValues(i)
        arrRows(i) = emptyCellRow
        arrValues(i) = Cells(emptyCellRow, 5).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next cell

If bIsEmpty = True Then
    For Each emptyRow In arrRows
        emptyRows = emptyRows & " " & emptyRow & " "
    Next emptyRow

    For Each emptyRow In arrValues
        emptyValues = emptyValues & " " & emptyRow & " "
    Next emptyRow
End If

If bIsEmpty = False Then
    MsgBox "All cells are filled in"
Else
    MsgBox "Empty rows: " & emptyRows
    MsgBox "Values in empty rows: " & emptyValues
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That was fast! This worked really well, thank you. I noticed it only returns the contents of the first row that is empty. I was hoping to return the contents of all the rows with an empty cell, separated by a comma or something similar. For example: "Values in column E are: a, b, c"...

Comment: Check edited code. If it is correct please approve answer :)

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that if both cells are empty in the same row it would only return the contents of the cell in column E once?

Comment: Hi again,Sorry I didn't test this before but I noticed now that when no cell in the range is empty I get a runtime error (92) For Loop not initialzed. Points at this one:    For Each emptyRow In arrRows

Comment: Edited answer - added a check to verify if at least one cell is empty.